# Where does V8's large object space reside?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, v8

As the title says, I'm trying to find out where does V8's large object space resides. I've done some experiments in Node JS where I load considerably large objects (+50mb) into memory. From what I understand, these objects should be directly stored into the large object space. However, `process.memoryUsage()` shows no signs of storing these objects whatsoever. But the objects must be somewhere... So, where is the large object space if not in the process' heap?

In [an old commit in V8's repository](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/5.1.281.35/src/heap/spaces.h#2966) I stumbled upon, it reads:

> Large objects ( > Page::kMaxRegularHeapObjectSize ) are allocated and
>   managed by the large object space. A large object is allocated from OS
>   heap with extra padding bytes (Page::kPageSize +
>   Page::kObjectStartOffset). A large object always starts at
>   Page::kObjectStartOffset to a page. Large objects do not move during
>   garbage collections.

And so I wonder:

- What does it mean it's allocating large objects from the operative system's heap? As far as I know, heaps are bound to tasks, and I don't understand how V8 could be storing memory into a heap that is not of its own, more over the operative system's heap. I must be wrong here, so correct me please!
- Is this the reason why my Node JS process shows normal memory consumption?

Thank you!

Comment: A useful overview of different types of storage in node.js here: https://deepu.tech/memory-management-in-v8/ and a description in the actual source here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/5.1.281.35/src/heap/spaces.h.

Answer (score 1):

> What does it mean it's allocating large objects from the operative system's heap?

It's requesting memory from the OS.

> Where does V8's large object space reside?

In the process' (heap) memory, just like all other spaces.

> I've done some experiments in Node JS

If you provided more details, I could take a better guess at what may have been happening. Maybe you were using TypedArrays? Those are handled specially, their backing stores (above a certain size) are not stored on the managed heap.

Comment: hey! I performed some tests passing large files over http to a node js server running on Hapi. I couldn't detect the files being stored in memory although they where being correctly sent and received. I performed the experiment again, this time with no middleware, and I managed to detect the files being stored in the heap! Perhaps Hapi is doing something weird or I just didn't perform the test accordingly (which is the most likely case). Thank you for your clarification, it was the answer I was looking for!